# Во()избежание

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно пишется слово "во()избежание": слитно или раздельно? Просто слитное написание Ворд подчеркивает.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Сложные предлоги *во избежание*, *в продолжение*, *в течение* пишутся раздельно. Предлог *вследствие* пишется слитно.

Answer (score 2):

Производный предлог ВО ИЗБЕЖАНИЕ пишется раздельно.

Из толкового словаря: ВО ИЗБЕЖАНИЕ чего, предлог с род. п. (книжн.) - уклоняясь от чего-н.,   в  целях  неосуществления  чего-н.  (неприятного).  Во  избежание недоразумений. Промолчать во избежание ссоры.

Производные предлоги, образованные на основе существительных, могут писаться как слитно, так и раздельно. Производный предлог имеет раздельное написание, если элементарный предлог в  составе производного предлога сохраняет предложное управление: избежание ссоры - во избежание (В.п.) ссоры (Р.п.).